# HTTPS Certificate error

Tags: windows, https, certificate

I have a telephone system in my office which hosts its administration interface on a local webserver secured by https. When I try to access the interface I always get a certificate error, even after installing the cert via Certmgr.exe.

Is there any way other way to install the certificate and to block this annoying error?

The message says " The organisation, issued the cert, is not trustworth."

Comment: How did you exactly get the certificate? What is the exact error that is displayed?

Comment: There is an error with the certificate of the website.
Then I click load the website anyway and ignore the error. Then I click on certificate info next to the adress bar in the browser. A messages pops up and then I click on install certificate.

Comment: There should be details available of the exact error. There can be several types of errors, untrusted issuer, expired certificate etc. The exact error must be known before an answer can be given.

Comment: There is a problem with the organisation, which issued the certificate. I think the certificate is self signed and not created by an organization like StarTSL. The message says " The organisation, issued the cert,  is not trustworth."

Answer (score 1):

> I always get a certificate error, even after installing the cert via Certmgr.exe

The browser is doing the certificate security checks, so you would have to refer to the browser's documentation for installing certificates. `certmgr.msc` is able to install a certificate into the Windows Certificate Store, which is used to check certificates by Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

The common approach to get a self-signed certificate to be accepted as valid by one of these browsers is [to install it into the "Trusted Roots" certification store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate.aspx) in your user's profile. You explicitly will have to select the store upon installation, as the default selection will let it end up in the "Personal" store, where it would not be checked against by the browsers.

Mind that installing a certificate into "Trusted Roots" might come with security hazards as trusting a certificate as a root would *also* mean trusting all certificates signed by this entity as a CA - which might become a problem if an adversary gets at the self-signed certificate's private key. I would first try installing it into the "Trusted People" and see if this helps matters - as opposed to "Trusted Roots" the certificates in the "Trusted People" store are not considered capable of signing other certificates.

Comment: I followed the guide, but I still get the same error. Btw the user, I'm working on is a domain user. As browser I tried internet explorer and chrome.

Comment: @user2147674 could you remove the cert from "trusted roots" and install it into "trusted people" instead? Alternately, install into *both* "trusted roots" and "trusted people"?

Comment: @user2147674 also, what *is* the browser version and the client OS version you are using?